# Expanding macros inside dolist

Tags: function, emacs, macros, lisp, eval

How can I expand a macro that adds symbols to the `obarray` (here `defun`) inside another loop macro like a `dolist`?  For example,

```
(defmacro make-cmd (cmd &optional search)
  "Some function factory."
  (let ((fn (intern (concat "fn-" cmd))))
    `(defun ,fn (&optional args)
       (interactive)
       (let ((str (symbol-name ',fn))
             ,@(when search
                 '((dir "~"))))
         (message "Called %S from %S" str
                  (or (and (bound-and-true-p dir) dir)
                      default-directory))))))

;; functions `fn-f1' and `fn-f2' aren't added to obarray
(dolist (x '("f1" "f2"))
  `(make-cmd ,x t))

;; works like this
(make-cmd "f1" t)
```

I would like to be able to just require the macros when compiling and loop over function names.  A common-lisp solution would probably be fine to adapt to emacs-lisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another typical solution in Common Lisp is to write a macro `defcmds` so that you can write:

```
(defcmds ("f1" 1) ("f2" t))
```

Which one would make expand into:

```
(progn
  (defcmd "f1" t)
  (defcmd "f2" t))
```

Where the`defcmd` forms would expand into

```
(progn
  (defun ...)
  (defun ...))
```

Answer (score 3):

(Others have answered your direct question.  But this might answer the question behind your question and speak to what you are really trying to do.  If not, see the other answers.)

You *do **not** need a macro* at all, to do what you want.  Just use `defalias` or `fset`.  Each is a *function*.

```el
(defun foo (cmd &optional search)
  (let ((fn  (intern (concat "fn-" cmd))))
    (defalias fn `(lambda (&optional args)
                    (let ((str  (symbol-name ',fn))
                          ,@(when search
                                  '((dir "~"))))
                      (message "Called %S from %S" str
                               (or (and (bound-and-true-p 'dir) dir)
                                   default-directory)))))))

(dolist (x  '("f1" "f2")) (foo x))
```

Then `(symbol-function 'fn-f1)` returns:

```el
(lambda (&optional args)
  (let ((str  (symbol-name 'fn-f1)))
    (message "Called %S from %S" str (or (and (bound-and-true-p dir) dir)
                                         default-directory))))
```

---

And if you use **lexical binding** (i.e., put the local-variable binding `-*- lexical-binding: t -*-` at the top of the file where this code is defined, then you don't need any of the backquoting.  For example:

```el
(defun foo (cmd &optional search)
  (let ((fn  (intern (concat "fn-" cmd))))
    (defalias fn (lambda (&optional args)
                    (let ((str  (symbol-name fn))
                          (dir  (if search "~" default-directory)))
                      (message "Called %S from %S" str dir))))))

(dolist (x  '("f1" "f2")) (foo x))
```

If you do that then each function `fn-f1` and `fn-f2` is defined as a closure, which looks like this:

```el
(symbol-function 'fn-f1)

(closure
 ((fn . fn-f1)
  (search)
  (cmd . "f1")
  t)
 (&optional args)
 (let ((str  (symbol-name fn))
       (dir  (if search "~" default-directory)))
   (message "Called %S from %S" str dir)))
```

And `(foo "f3" :SEARCH)` defines a function `fn-f3` (a closure) that encapsulates a binding of otherwise free variable `search` to the non-`nil` value `:SEARCH`, so that local variable `dir` becomes bound to `"~"`:

```el
(symbol-function 'fn-f3)

(closure
 ((fn . fn-f3)
  (search . :SEARCH)  ;; <==============
  (cmd . "f3")
  t)
 (&optional args)
 (let ((str  (symbol-name fn))
       (dir  (if search "~" default-directory)))
   (message "Called %S from %S" str dir)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
(dolist (x '("f1" "f2"))
  (eval `(make-cmd ,x t)))
```

The backquote expression `` `(make-cmd ,x t) `` only constructs the syntax. That syntax isn't evaluated. It's the same thing as if you had written `(list 'make-cmd x t)`.

If the primary use for this `make-cmd` macro calls for `eval`, it might as well be turned into a function:

```
(defun make-cmd-fun (cmd &optional search)
  "Some function factory."
  (let ((fn (intern (concat "fn-" cmd))))
    `(defun 
       ...)))
```

Now you have a plain function which returns `defun` syntax; and that of course has to be `eval`-ed to put it into effect. But now we don't have to construct any more syntax at the call site where we use the macro:

```
(dolist (x '("f1" "f2"))
  ;; Note how at least the backquote is gone (but not eval).
  (eval (make-cmd-fun x t))) ;; execute the defun form returned by make-cmd-fun
```

When we have `make-cmd-fun`, we can then define the macro version in terms of it:

```
(defmacro make-cmd (cmd &optional search)
  (make-cmd-fun cmd search))
```

Basically we have made the raw macro expander function available as `make-cmd-fun`; the macro `make-cmd` just calls that expander.